# Creating a new array in a do loop using the 'Each' method

Tags: ruby, methods

Let's say I have the following array:
`array = [1, 2, 3, 4]`
From here, I'd like to create a new array where I manipulate elements of the original array using a do loop.  So, in creating this new array, shouldn't I be able to populate each new element in a loop? -

```
array.each do |number|
  new_array = array.new[element]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is what you're saying:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

array.each do |number|
    new_array = number * 2
    print(new_array, " ")
end
```

will give the output `2  4  6  8  10`, basically "manipulating elements of the original array using a do loop (multiplying by a constant, for example)"

Comment: Ok this is what I was trying to figure out, thanks.